# Is this a valid alternative proof of the sum law in limits?

Tags: limits, alternative-proof

So sum law of limits tell us

> > $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)=X + Y$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = X$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = Y$

Here is my attempt to prove it.

> *Proof*
>
> Let $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$, then $\exists N_a,N_b:$
>
> (1) $|a_n - X| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $n> N_a$
>
> (2) $|b_n - Y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$  whenever $n> N_b$
>
> Add (1) and (2) to get $|a_n - X| + |b_n-Y| < \epsilon \implies |a_n + b_n - (X + Y)| \leq |a_n - X| + |b_n-Y| < \epsilon \iff |a_n + b_n - (X + Y)| < \epsilon$
>
> By setting $N=max\left \{ N_a,N_b \right \}$, we get the result.

I consulted an analysis book and they kinda did the same thing, but I think I worked backwards by adding (1) and (2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exist positive integers $N_a$ and $N_b$ such that $|a_n-X|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $n>N_a$ and $|b_n-Y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $n>N_b$. Let $N$ be the maximum of $N_a$ and $N_b$. Then for all $n>N$, we have $|a_n+b_n-(X+Y)|\leq|a_n-X|+|b_n-Y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

Comment: why do we (or I guess you lol) start with $|a_n+b_n-(X+Y)|$ first? Why can't I start with $|a_n-X|+|b_n-Y|$ first?

Comment: Becausew your goal is to prove that $|a_n+b_n-L|$ can be as small as you want, where $L$ is the limit of the sum. Here you take $L=X+Y$ because you "feel" it should be this.

Comment: Because inequality $|a_n + b_n - (X + Y)| < |a_n - X| + |b_n-Y|$ not always hold

Comment: @M.Strochyk, a typo on my part. Would it be alright then if I replace < with <= in my proof? I'll do it now

Comment: Okay I'll clean it up now and wait for your comments!

Comment: It always bugs me when, in these types of proof, people use magic constants with $\epsilon$ ($\epsilon/2$ here) so the result comes out bounded by $\epsilon$. Just use $\epsilon$ in the analysis, and if the bound comes out $2\epsilon$ or $10 \epsilon$ or whatever, as long as it is a finite number times $\epsilon$, that is good enough.

Comment: *you cannot add the inequalities without defining the condition first on n.* Can you elaborate on this? Under what conditions (on n) will my method work?

Comment: Okay, but we need to extend the comment box for that message thing to come up

Answer (score 4):

By the triangle inequality
$|a_n + b_n - X  - Y|  \leqslant |a_n  - X|+| b_n  - Y| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$ $\forall n\geqslant N=\max\left \{ N_a,N_b \right \}$